# How to delete image from firebase cloud storage

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage

I have made a social media app where users can upload there pic. I want to add a delete option for the users in the app. I want the users to delete their pic from Firebase cloud storage. Here is my code

```
val photoRef: StorageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(contentDTOs[p1].imageUrl.toString())
photoRef.delete().addOnSuccessListener { // File deleted successfully
    Toast.makeText(context, "onSuccess: deleted file",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}.addOnFailureListener { // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
    Toast.makeText(context, "onFailure: did not delete file",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}

return@setOnLongClickListener true
```

But whenever I try to delete any pic it returns me error

```
E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
    Object does not exist at location.
     Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404
E/StorageException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found.  Could not delete object",    "status": "DELETE_OBJECT"  }}
    java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found.  Could not delete object",    "status": "DELETE_OBJECT"  }}
```

Comment: It looks like `contentDTOs[p1].imageUrl.toString()` does not refer to a file in your Cloud Storage bucket.

Comment: It returns me the pictures uploaded by the users the in imageview

Comment: What if you print the retrieved value? 1. `contentDTOs[p1].imageUrl.toString()`. Then check manually whether the object exists in your Bucket. You can use the tool [`gsutil`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/gcp-integration#gsutil), try with the command: `gsutil ls gs://YourBucket/YoutFileName`.

Comment: Yes my images exists in the storage and by using contentDTOs[p1].imageUrl I retrieve images in the image view